# Cardinality of set of all rectangles on a plane

Tags: solution-verification, cardinals

The set of rectangles in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with sides parallel to axes and bottom-left corner in origin can be described as:$$\mathcal{R}=\{[0,a]\times[0,b]:a,b\in\mathbb{R}\}$$
There is bijection $\mathcal{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $[0,a]\times[0,b]\mapsto(a,b)$
Hence I get: $|\mathbb{R}^2|=|\mathbb{R}| = \mathfrak{c}$

How would you expand this on all rectangles including translated and rotated?
My idea is to extend cartesian product with coordinates of bottom-left corner - $[x,y]$ and rotation - $\phi$:
$$\mathcal{R}=\{[0,a]\times[0,b] \times [x, y] \times \phi:a,b,x,y,\phi\in\mathbb{R}\}$$
With bijection: $$\mathcal{R}\to\mathbb{R}^5 \quad \text{due to:} \quad[0,a]\times[0,b]\times[x,y]\times\phi\mapsto(a,b,x,y,\phi)$$
Of cardinality:
$$|\mathbb{R}^5|=|\mathbb{R}| = \mathfrak{c}$$
I was also thinking about directly defining unique rectangle on a plane with three points, but the above, if correct, requires less data - $(a,b,x,y,\phi)$ vs $(x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2,x_3,y_3)$.
Anyway, would love to hear your opinions or interesting ways of defining unique rotated/translated rectangle on a plane with minimum variables.

Comment: You could give its center $(x,y)$, its circumradius $R$ and the angles of its diagonales $\phi, \psi$. Those are $5$ parameters. I wouldn't know how to formalize this, but **you will need $5$ degrees of freedom to determine any rectangle**. Of course, the formalization of such statement will need to somehow exclude "cheating" (using  that $|\Bbb R^n| = |\Bbb R|$).

Comment: You can also do it by identifying any rectangle with the pair of diagonally opposite points and the smaller interior angle between the diagonal given by the points and a side. Or by 2 consecutive vertices and the length of the sides perpendicular to the segment they describe. I also don't see how you would do this with less than $5$ variables assuming the variables are supposed to be real (and not, as @jjagmath pointed out, 'cheating' variables, e.g. considering the position of a point in the plane as a single variable).

Comment: How computable do you want your answer to be?

Comment: @R.Burton: numerically? Not at all. Just want to "count" the rectangles and make sure that none got accounted more than once.

Comment: Perhaps a simpler/more elegant way is to notice that a transformation from the unit square to any rectangle in the plane can be decomposed into a sequence of transformations, i.e. It can be described as the composition of a vertical stretch, a horizontal stretch, a vertical translation, horizontal translation and a rotation. And then since each of these transformations are parameterised by a single real parameter, the cardinality of the resulting set's cardinality gets "multiplied" by the continuum each time, and then you just need to know that $|\mathbb{R}|^2= |\mathbb{R}|$